# Add font family and font size in UIPickerView

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, font-size, picker, font-family

I'm a newbie to iOS programming, I have a project and my requirements are

1: I have to add font family

2: In the same way, I have to add font size

These are to be added with a done button on top and a bifurcation in between them.

Guys I have searched and cant get it, kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which bits can't you do, the picker view or getting the font families, or both? At the moment this is a requirement, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your picker view should have two components.
- The number of rows in the first component should be the count of the items in your font family list.
- The number of rows in the second component should be the count of the number of size options you wish to offer.

These numbers are controlled by the picker view [datasource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). There are only two methods in this protocol.

- The title for each individual row should be either the name of the font family at the relevant index in your list, or the font size option.

This is covered by the picker view [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html) method `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`

Your datasource and delegate are typically the same object, usually the view controller that is presenting the picker.

Comment: Thanks for the ans.. I'm trying!

Comment: I'm done with all of the requirement, my only question is how to add Font Family onto the picker view? Kindly help me with this, I'm almost done with my school project.

Comment: [UIFont familyNames] gives you an array of all the font families available.

Comment: Yeah I tried and thats working... thanks for that bro, my next big challenge is how do i add system generated fonts to the other component in PickerView?

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you can accept it using the check mark symbol under the answer score. Your next challenge is a new question!