# Font family into UIPickerView

Tags: xcode, fonts, uipickerview, font-size, picker

I have to get all the system generated fonts onto a UIPickerView.

Kindly let me know if there are any ways to do it?

I have tried through initializing NSMutableArray through the UIFont, but that isnt working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add font family and font size in UIPickerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148764/add-font-family-and-font-size-in-uipickerview)

Comment: See my comment on my answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];
```

Gives you an array of all the font family names available.